# How to load div on var hash example #index2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, hashtag

Its my button:

```
<a href="#index2"></a>
<div id="page-wrapper"></div>
$("#index2").click(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#page-wrapper').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('#page-wrapper').load("index2.php", function(){
                $('#page-wrapper').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Its successfully work and no problem but this does not work if the page refreshes

And that's when you refresh the page on the www.domain.com/index.php#index2 page

Now how can i load again `index2.php` to `#page-wrapper` on refresh?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better approach to use `hashchange` event to handle # anchor changes. Try like this;

```
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        var loadUrl = hash.substr(1) + ".php";
        $('#page-wrapper').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('#page-wrapper').load(loadUrl, function(){
                $('#page-wrapper').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });
    });
```

To fire `hashchange` event **at first page load** you can try;

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        $(window).trigger('hashchange')
    }
});
```

Comment: True but it does not work in refresh the page. it just work on change hash i want work after refresh page look my answer ;)

Comment: You are right, i missed that detail. I updated my answer.